# What's the difference between string interning and string pooling in .NET?

Tags: .net, string, clr

I have read several articles, but still didn't get what the difference between string interning and string pooling is in .NET. Especially, the case when those mechanisms are applied together. Could you give an example with explanation?

Comment: Just a different term for the same? Afaik they are synonymous.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Maybe it sounds funny, but there are two different chapters for each of these techniques in the well-known "CLR via C#" book by J.Richter. I couldn't see the difference after reading, that's why after surfing the web I post this question here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, they are just alternate terms for describing the same thing.

Consider the following statement [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx):

> The Intern method uses the intern pool to search for a string equal to the value of str.

Notice the use of the phrase "intern pool", this indicates how the two separate terms may have arisen for the same meaning

Answer (score 1):

String interning is a feature built into the CLI that facilitates using the same string instance when the same sequence of characters is seen. This does not apply to all `string` instances - it only applies to:

- strings created via the `ldstr` IL command, which is used when code contains a literal - i.e. `Console.WriteLine("abc")` (here `"abc"` is the literal that is baked into the IL and loaded via `ldstr`)
- code that explicitly uses the `string.Intern` method

It is hard to tell without context, but I strongly suspect that "string pooling" is simply being used as a synonym for "interning".

Note that it is also possible for code to work with a private pool / interning set, for example by using a `Dictionary<string,string>`. This might be useful to re-use the strings *in a particular scope*, but without saturating the application-wide intern pool. Any such device would be bespoke and application specific.